# find maximum GCD of an array of triplets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, number-theory, greatest-common-divisor, array-algorithms

you are given an array of triplets of size N, we have to choose one number from each triplet, forming a new array of N size, such that the GCD of the numbers in the new array is maximum.

example:
an array of triplets where N=3 -

```
[(70, 105, 42),
(35, 60, 210),
(36, 70, 420)]
```

so if we choose 105 from first element, 210 from second and 420 from third, we get a GCD of 105. which is the maximum possible answer.

when I used brute force, I got time limit exceeded (since there are exponential possibilities to check).
I couldn't think of a way to use dynamic programming here, and apart from that I am unsure how to proceed with this question.

Comment: What is the maximum size n? The  maximum value of an element?

Comment: Assuming 3 levels of nodes with a root node at the top, now the problem is to find the optimal path. DFS with memoization(caching and using GCD of 2 numbers) will reduce the time complexity.

Comment: Bounds for N and the range of the integers would be helpful. There's a very easy O(NK) algorithm where K is min(max(T) for T in array). Algo puzzles copied to stackoverflow should reproduce ALL of the information in the question! (And/or a link to the original).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can maintain a list of possible gcds. If the first triple is (a0, a1, a2), you start with `set(a0, a1, a2)`. Then for the second triple `(b0, b1, b2)` you take the gcd of each element with every element of your set. So: `(gcd(a0, b0), gcd(a0, b1), gcd(a0, b2), gcd(a1, b0), gcd(a1, b1), gcd(a1, b2), gcd(a2, b0), gcd(a2, b1), gcd(a2, b2))`. And so on.

At each step, you could remove any element in your set that's a factor of any other. (It's probably not worthwhile to do this though).

Once you've processed every triple, the largest value in your set is your answer.

It looks like this set might grow exponentially, but it's bounded by a function of K (the maximum value in any triple in the array): the number of elements in your set can never be larger than the number of factors of all three elements in any triple, which is o(K^eps) for all eps>0, and in practice will be smaller. For example, if all of your numbers are less than 1 billion, the set will never be larger than 4032 (the largest number of factors of any number less than 1 billion is 1344, and 4032 = 3*1344).

That means this algorithm does O(NK^eps) gcd operations for all eps>0.

Comment: nice solution, just a doubt, why do you say that the set can grow to 1344 * 3? Do we really need more than one copy for each possible GCD?

Comment: Because there can be factors from each of three numbers in a triplet. It's an easy upper bound, and I guess in practice the size of the set is much smaller.

Comment: hi, thanks for this solution. I had tried to keep a list of the possible gcd while going through the array, however I had stored in a queue rather then a Set. Do you think that is why it may have exceeded the time limit?

Comment: If you don't de-dupe entries then the queue will get 3 times longer each tuple, so will not be a good solution either in time or space.